# which one is better when I tried to ask the photographer edit my photo?

Tags: word-choice

When I take a photo and there is some hair in disorder, how should I ask the photographer to edit it for me? Should I say

> "Could you edit those hair in disorder for me?"

or

> "Could you erase the tousle for me? "

Which one is better?

Comment: I would phrase it like this: "Can you fix my hair in this photograph using an editing program like *Adobe Photoshop* or *PortraitPro*?"

Answer (score 1):

Hair can be

> tousled

[image: here]

> messy

[image: here]

> misplaced

[image: here]

each describes the general look of the hair as a whole.

It is much easier to say to the editor to

> Please fix my hair so it's not so tousled / messy / misplaced.

[image: here]

Or you could also say

> Please erase those *loose hairs* for me.

While pointing to the hairs you are talking about.

Comment: Pity the viewer on a mobile, @Peter. Are humongous images a considerate choice? Nice hair porn, though.

Answer (score 1):

> When I take a photo and there is some hair in disorder, how should I ask the photographer to edit it for me?

Ask the photographer to *touch it up*.  If you are filling out a form, check the box marked "touch-up".

**Please do a little touching up -- I don't need much -- just remove the stray hairs, please.**